# Changing order of seaborn lineplot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, format, seaborn

I have a small [`pd.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) that looks like this:

| Col1 | NumCol |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 10000000 |
| 1 | 7500000 |
| 2 | 12500000 |
| 3 | 37500000 |
| 4 | 110000000 |
| 5 | 65000000 |

`NumCol` is actually dollar values.

I want to create a `seaborn lineplot`, but instead of using the numerical values which create a funky looking axis, I'd like to show dollar values.

`sns.lineplot(data=plot_df, x='Col1', y='NumCol')` properly creates:
[image]

However, I'd like the axes to show `$10,000,000`, `$7,500,000`, etc.
I know I can create a string-representation of the column using

`plot_df['NumCol_Str'] = plot_df.NumCol.apply(lambda x : "${:,}".format(x))`

Which creates:

| Col1 | NumCol | NumCol_Str |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10000000 | $10,000,000 |
| 1 | 7500000 | $7,500,000 |
| 2 | 12500000 | $12,500,000 |
| 3 | 37500000 | $37,500,000 |
| 4 | 110000000 | $110,000,000 |
| 5 | 65000000 | $65,000,000 |

However, when plotting, it changes the order of the columns

`sns.lineplot(data=plot_df, x='Col1', y='NumCol_Str')`

[image]

How can I properly plot the linegraph while keeping the new string notation on the axis?

[MRE below:](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

```
plot_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Col1': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5},
 'NumCol': {0: 10000000,
  1: 7500000,
  2: 12500000,
  3: 37500000,
  4: 110000000,
  5: 65000000}})
plot_df['NumCol_Str'] = plot_df.NumCol.apply(lambda x : "${:,}".format(x))
sns.lineplot(data=plot_df, x='Col1', y='NumCol_Str')
sns.lineplot(data=plot_df, x='Col1', y='NumCol')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just plot using the numeric values and then change the axis formatter with matplotlib tick formatter:

```
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.StrMethodFormatter('${x:,.0f}'))
```

EDIT:
Or even simpler as pointed out by @BigBen:

```
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter('${x:,.0f}')
```

Comment: @BigBen Cool thanks, didn't realize that was possible.